# How to get ALT from IMG tag in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress, lightbox

I am using [THIS](http://ashleydw.github.io/lightbox/) script to display my galleries in lightbox. I was using some plugins but all of them does not display the alt=""(alt added in media in wordpress).

How can I modify the code from the link below to display the alt attributes ?

I found something in the code, but I dont know how to put the dynamic alt there(commented by uppercase text in the code). Dynamic I mean that as user will add the img in wordpress dashboard, he will put the alt then.

```
{
            key: '_preloadImage',
            value: function _preloadImage(src, $containerForImage) {
                var _this4 = this;

                $containerForImage = $containerForImage || false;

                var img = new Image();
                if ($containerForImage) {
                    (function () {

                        // if loading takes > 200ms show a loader
                        var loadingTimeout = setTimeout(function () {
                            $containerForImage.append(_this4._config.loadingMessage);
                        }, 200);

                        img.onload = function () {
                            if (loadingTimeout) clearTimeout(loadingTimeout);
                            loadingTimeout = null;
                            var image = $('<img />');
                            image.attr('src', img.src);
                            image.addClass('img-fluid');
image.attr('alt',"Temp TEXT"); // HERE I WOULD LIKE TO DISPLAY THE ALT AUTOMATICALLY - NOT STATIC AS IT IS NOW

                            // backward compatibility for bootstrap v3
                            image.css('width', '100%');

                            $containerForImage.html(image);
                            if (_this4._$modalArrows) _this4._$modalArrows.css('display', ''); // remove display to default to css property

                            _this4._resize(img.width, img.height);
                            _this4._toggleLoading(false);
                            return _this4._config.onContentLoaded.call(_this4);
                        };
                        img.onerror = function () {
                            _this4._toggleLoading(false);
                            return _this4._error(_this4._config.strings.fail + ('  ' + src));
                        };
                    })();
                }

                img.src = src;
                return img;
            }
        },
```

I am using wordpress on my page and my skills in JS are rather poor, so I am asking you :).

Comment: So read the alt like you do with the src?

Comment: I was trying to do so...

`functions.js?ver=4.9.3:874 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).ekkoLightbox is not a function
    at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (functions.js?ver=4.9.3:874)
    at HTMLDocument.dispatch (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:3)
    at HTMLDocument.r.handle (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:3)
(anonymous) @ functions.js?ver=4.9.3:874
dispatch @ jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:3
r.handle @ jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:3`

Answer (score 1):

We don't really know what is the type of your `img` variable. If you want to set the alt tag of `image` to the one of `img`, simply do:

```
image.attr('alt', img.attr('alt'));
```

…if it's a jQuery object. Otherwise, if `img` is pure JavaScript, you can do:

```
image.attr('alt', img.alt);
```

Comment: I have an error to your solution

`ekko-lightbox.js?ver=4.9.3:549 Uncaught TypeError: img.attr is not a function
    at Image.img.onload (ekko-lightbox.js?ver=4.9.3:549)
img.onload @ ekko-lightbox.js?ver=4.9.3:549`

Comment: What if you try `image.attr('alt', this.alt);` or `image.attr('alt', $(this).attr('alt'));`?

Comment: The second one did not display alt, but the first one displayed the empty `alt=""`. I have typed `console.log(this);` and It throw the `<img src="here is the source">` . There is no alt, but for sure I have added it in wordpress while I was adding the img.

Answer (score 0):

if the `img` object holds the existing alt and `image` is the new jQuery object, then set it with jQuery

```
image.attr('alt', img.getAttribute('alt'))
```

Comment: Not working

`Uncaught TypeError: image.setAttribute is not a function
    at Image.img.onload (ekko-lightbox.js?ver=4.9.3:549)
img.onload @ ekko-lightbox.js?ver=4.9.3:549`